# How to dowload large file faster with multiple conections and multiprocessing using Request module along with progress bar

Tags: python, download, multiprocessing

I have a code to download a file that requires persistent session and cookies.
Below is the code i am using:

```
import lxml.html as htmlparser
import regex, math, enlighten
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url='https://serverlink.com/vid/XXXYYY'
URL = "https://serverhomepage.com/"

CONTENT_ID = regex.compile(r"/vid/([^?#&/]+)")
csrf_token = (
        htmlparser.fromstring(session.get(url).text)
        .cssselect("meta[name='csrf-token']")[0]
        .get("content")
    )


content_id = CONTENT_ID.search(url).group(1)
stream = session.post(
        URL + "api/vid/get&user=xxx&pass=yyy",
        headers={
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "x-csrf-token": csrf_token,
        },
        json={"id": content_id},
    ).json().get("result").get("Link")



res = session.head(stream)
rt = res.headers.get("Location")
r = session.get(rt, stream=True)
fname='vid.mp4'
MANAGER = enlighten.get_manager()
assert r.status_code == 200, r.status_code
dlen = int(r.headers.get('Content-Length', '0')) or None

with MANAGER.counter(color = 'green', total = dlen and math.ceil(dlen / 2 ** 20), unit = 'MiB', leave = False) as ctr, \
     open(fname, 'wb', buffering = 2 ** 24) as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 2 ** 20):
        f.write(chunk)
        ctr.update()
```

Normally a bash Programmer
Just a beginner in python. So far able to use request module and download single file as whole.

Opted to use python because it make it easy to implement multithreading, multiprocessing & asyncrounous processes
I am using above code to download file and show progress.

**Will someone help to make my script download file via multiple chunk using either ThreadPool or Multiprocessing or asyncio. Want to download file as fast as possible.**

**I want to implement concurrent multichunked download. Server speed doesnt matter. I just want to make sure file is being download at maximum possiblr speed without any error. even there is chnce of getting 100kb rise in speed upon multithreading i want to impement it. Just want to make sure file is being downloaded most efficientlt at max possible speed**

Want solution that uses request module session. As the file i am trying to download doesnt work easily with urllib.
I have searched many scripts to implement fast concurrent download but they all use urllib. I dont have any experience with urllib

I have tried to follow good question practice. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Tried IDM and aria2c. They can download within 5-10 mins. But my file requires cookie session passing thats why i had to use python.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a 1 Mbit/s network? It would match with the provided timings. There is no reason for Python not saturating your bandwidth here I think. Async is possible between multiple files but it looks like there is only one file here. If this is not due to your network, then maybe the server is limiting the throughput. Besides an important point to reach a high throughput is to check the latency is not huge. Otherwise, bigger bugger are needed, including the OS TCP stack parameter (like the TCP window size).

Comment: I want to implement concurrent multichunked download. Server speed doesnt matter. I just want to make sure file is being download at maximum possiblr speed without any error. even there is chnce of getting 100kb rise in speed upon multithreading i want to impement it.

Comment: i havent asked question why my download is slow. i want help regarding how to use python to fast downlaod file specifically with request module. i have searched all tutorials anr scripts on google/github but they all use urllib. and i want multichunked concurrent with request module. Can you help with tha???